# How to say "a blue-ruled Olympic Exercise notebook" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I wondered what the meaning is in Chinese.

Also there are other different types in printing, like Graph ruled, wide ruled. If I can call them "蓝边"  "图纹"  and "宽边笔记本"?

Comment: I think you should use `线`, such as `蓝线笔记本`, `宽线笔记本`. `Graph ruled`...`图案线`?

Comment: I thought about "线“，but considering that here is also a Graph, so I don't know for sure. Maybe it has a common name for "ruled".

Comment: The common name should be `线`. `边` doesn't make sense, because it means `border`. `Graph ruled` might need more considerations, and the translation might be changing depend on what graph being used as the line. BTW: `图纹` is not bad.

Comment: iciba：graph paper n. 方格纸
also sample sentences with  图表纸,图纸

Comment: A blue-rules notebook 蓝横格本

Answer (score 1):

A blue-rules notebook 蓝横格本

rule, 横格
grid, 方格